# SSIS 2005 Control Flow Priority

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

The short version is I am looking for a way to prioritize certain tasks in SSIS 2005 control flows.  That is I want to be able to set it up so that Task B does not start until Task A has started but Task B does not need to wait for Task A to complete.  The goal is to reduce the amount of time where I have idle threads hanging around waiting for Task A to complete so that they can move onto Tasks C, D & E.

The issue I am dealing with is converting a data warehouse load from a linear job that calls a bunch of SPs to an SSIS package calling the same SPs but running multiple threads in parallel.  So basically I have a bunch of Execute SQL Task and Sequence Container objects with Precedent Constraints mapping out the dependencies.  So far no problems, things are working great and it cut our load time a bunch.

However I noticed that tasks with no downstream dependencies are commonly being sequenced before those that do have dependencies.  This is causing a lot of idle time in certain spots that I would like to minimize.

For example: I have about 60 procs involved with this load, ~10 of them have no dependencies at all and can run at any time.  Then I have another one with no upstream dependencies but almost every other task in the job is dependent on it.  I would like to make sure that the task with the dependencies is running before I pick up any of the tasks with no dependencies.  This is just one example, there are similar situations in other spots as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am late in updating over here but I also raised this issue over on the MSDN forums and we were able to devise a partial work around.  See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/579b9f3a-5e66-41a9-940e-0b08405a2441) for the full thread, or [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/614043/ssis-control-flow-priority) for the feature request asking microsoft to give us a way to do this cleanly...

The short version is that you use a series of Boolean variables to control loops that act like roadblocks and prevent the flow from reaching the lower priority tasks until the higher priority items have started.

The steps involved are:

- Declare a bool variable for each of the high priority tasks and default the values to false.
- Create a pre-execute event for each of the high priority tasks.
- In the pre-execute event create a script task which sets the appropriate bool to true.
- At each choke point insert a for each loop that will loop while the appropriate bool(s) are false. (I have a script with a 1 second sleep inside each loop but it also works with empty loops.)

If done properly this gives you a tool where at each choke point the package has some number of high priority tasks ready to run and a blocking loop that keeps it from proceeding down the lower priority branches until said high priority items are running. Once all of the high priority tasks have been started the loop clears and allows any remaining threads to move on to lower priority tasks. Worst case is one thread sits in the loop while waiting for other threads to come along and pick up the high priority tasks.

The major drawback to this approach is the risk of deadlocking the package if you have too many blocking loops get queued up at the same time, or misread your dependencies and have loops waiting for tasks that never start. Careful analysis is needed to decide which items deserved higher priority and where exactly to insert the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any elegant ways to do this but my first shot would be something like this..

Sequence Container with the proc that has to run first.  In that same sequence container put a script task that just waits 5-10 seconds or so before each of the 10 independent steps can run.  Then chain the rest of the procs below that sequence container.